# PHP Array key value next to each other to use in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i need to create chart based on php array and i found something about traversing in stackoverflow posts but those answers doesnt help for converting this:

```
Array
(
    [product sample 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [hitsTotal] => 63
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [hitsTotal] => 113
                )

        )

    [product sample 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [hitsTotal] => 57
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [hitsTotal] => 107
                )

        )
)
```

to

```
['product sample 1', 63, 113],
['product sample 2', 57, 107]
```

how to convert?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: @Rayon, thanks for reply, actually im new to chart and this is the latest dump after some coding i stuck on. i cant figure it out how to display javascript style out of this.

Comment: New to chart is not really relevant to how to iterate an array

Comment: @charlietfl, maybe not but how to iterate so?

Comment: @HamedOkhovvat this isn't a code writing service and you really should be showing some attempt to solve this yourself

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for your attempt ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$input` is the array you present in your post you can do the following:

```
$output = array();

foreach($input as $key => $value)
{
    $obj = array();
    $obj[] = $key;
    $obj[] = $value[0]['hitsTotal'];
    $obj[] = $value[1]['hitsTotal'];
    $output[] = $obj;
}


var_dump($output);  //This will print it on screen so you can validate the output
```

Comment: doesn't match structure in question

Comment: @charlietfl Corrected it

Comment: No it's not .. OP has associative sub arrays

Comment: @dimlucas, Thanks to you too.

Answer (score 0):

To prepare your data for passing to js(client side) as an array of arrays use the following approach (`array_walk`, `array_column`, `array_merge` and `json_encode` functions):

```
// supposing that $arr is your initial array
$result = [];
array_walk($arr, function($v, $k) use(&$result){
    $hitsTotals = array_column($v, 'hitsTotal');
    $result[] = array_merge([$k], $hitsTotals);
});

echo json_encode($result);
```

The output:

```
[["product sample 1",63,113],["product sample 2",57,107]]
```

Comment: Thanks for help and +1 for explanation.